# Why does lodash's _.sum() function fail Vuejs objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I'm using Vuejs and Lodash  and I have a computed property that simply sums a property of a collection. I've previously used `_.sum()` for this but when I use that with a vuejs vm it seems to just concatenate the string `[object Object]`!

I've made a [jsfiddle with the following code](http://jsfiddle.net/s1y8uqbo/):

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", time: 5 },
      { text: "Learn Vue", time: 10 },
      ]
  },
  computed: {
    additup() { return _.sum(this.todos, todo => todo.time ) },
    additup2() { return _.sum(this.todos, function (todo) {
      return parseInt(todo.time);
    })} },
    additup3() { 
      var t = 0; 
      _.each(this.todos, function(todo) { t+=todo.time; }); 
      return t; 
    }
  }
})
```

The output is:

> Method 1 gives: [object Object][object Object]
>   Method 2 gives: [object Object][object Object]
>   Method 3 gives: 15

Is there a way to fix `_.sum()`? Or a way to fix my understanding of why it's not working ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sumBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#sumBy) instead of `sum`:

> This method is like `_.sum` except that it accepts iteratee which is
>   invoked for each element in array to generate the value to be summed.
>   The iteratee is invoked with one argument: (value).

Comment: Ah, I think they must have changed the API from an earier version where [`_.sum()` also took an iteree](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#sum). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
additup() { return _.sum(this.todos.map(todo => todo.time)) },
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you set on `_.sum` and then mapping? Because you can simply do:

```
additup() { return _.sumBy(this.todos, 'time') }
```

Or with ES6 you could get even shorter by:

```
additup = () => _.sumBy(this.todos, 'time')
```

This is actually [_.sumBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#sumBy) main use-case.